# New SBT settings value doesn't take effect

Tags: scala, sbt

I have defined a settings key inside Tasks object

```
object Tasks {

  lazy val shouldCheckSnapshotDeps: SettingKey[Boolean] = settingKey[Boolean](
    "Should enforce SNAPSHOT check 'checkSnapshotDependencies'"
  )

  lazy val checkSnapshotDependencies: TaskKey[Unit] = taskKey[Unit](
    "Checks for SNAPSHOT dependencies and raise exception if any"
  )

  class SnapshotDepsException(message: String) extends FeedbackProvidedException

  lazy val checkSnapshotDependenciesTask: Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] = Def.task {
    val moduleIds = (managedClasspath in Runtime).value.flatMap(_.get(moduleID.key))
    val snapshotModules = moduleIds.filter(m => m.isChanging || m.revision.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"))

    if (snapshotModules.nonEmpty && shouldCheckSnapshotDeps.value) {
      val message = s"Found SNAPSHOT versions for ${snapshotModules.mkString(System.lineSeparator())}." +
        s" SNAPSHOTS are not allowed. Set settings for 'shouldCheckSnapshotDeps' to suppress this check"
      sys.error(message)
      throw new SnapshotDepsException(message)
    }
  }
}
```

I try to set the value using `sbt 'set Tasks.shouldCheckSnapshotDeps := false'`. However the new settings value set using command line doesn't seem to take effect. Also I see below in logs,

```
[info] Defining root/*:shouldCheckSnapshotDeps
[info] The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
```

The line `The new value will be used by no settings or tasks.` seems to convey my problem.

Default value for settings is set using

```
shouldCheckSnapshotDeps := true,
checkSnapshotDependencies := checkSnapshotDependenciesTask.value
```

Why does the new settings value set using `sbt 'set Tasks.shouldCheckSnapshotDeps := false'` NOT effective?

Task.scala is located as `project/Task.scala` in file system

Comment: This setting appears to be defined in an `object` called `Task`, correct? How is `Task` defined? Where is the file it is defined in located? Can you show the code that uses the value of the setting? Where is that located?

Comment: @MikeAllen Updated question to answer your query.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to declare settings as `lazy`. They need to be defined whether they're referenced or not. (Typically, making sequences of setting values, and projects, lazy ensures they do not take effect unless referenced, which is fine. But the settings themselves should always be defined, I would have thought.)

Comment: default value is set in project settings using shouldCheckSnapshotDeps := true,
        checkSnapshotDependencies := checkSnapshotDependenciesTask.value,

Comment: Can you show your `build.sbt` file (or equivalent) as well?

Comment: Also, in case it's relevant, what is the version of _SBT_ you're using?

Comment: Are you trying to set the property from the command line, via `sbt 'set Tasks.shouldCheckSnapshotDeps := true'`? If so, I think you need to use double quotes: `sbt "set Tasks.shouldCheckSnapshotDeps := true"`.

Comment: Settings are set properly as you can see from log entry in question. SBT 0.13.16

Comment: FWIW, your code works for me with _SBT_ 1.1.5. Can you switch to a later _SBT_ version?

Comment: That is interesting. Thanks for trying it out. Unfortunately cannot upgrade SBT.